# Python open url in browser, wait for manual login, read address bar URL from browser

Tags: python, url, browser

I am trying to automate getting an eBay API refresh token using Python. What I need it to do is:

1. Open a specific URL in the default browser
2. Wait for the user to log in
3. Read the new URL from the address bar in the browser

The code I have just now will only get the HTML from the URL and then the actual URL from the browser, but obviously doesn't open the page in a browser to allow the user to log in. I have just used google's log in page as I cannot give the URL of the page I am using as it contains very sensitive login details.

```
from urllib import request
url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.co.uk/&ec=GAZAmgQ"
response = request.urlopen(url)
new_url = response.geturl()
print(new_url)
```

Comment: The general way to achieve this is to open a local webserver from python, send it's url as the redirect target of whatever login you want, let the browser + user do its thing ending with a redirect to your webserver and then react accordingly. Of course that relies on the target website accepting such a redirect.

Comment: Read about Oauth flow

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this appears to do what I want. The selenium driver for Chrome needs to be in the system path for it to work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.co.uk/&ec=GAZAmgQ"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

while True:
    get_url = driver.current_url
    if "Login" not in get_url:
        break
    sleep(1)
print(get_url)
driver.close()
```

However, google says that the browser isn't secure when I test it, but it might work with eBay - I'll try it when I need to and report back...